# How to integrate $\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{dx}{\mathrm{sin}^4x +\mathrm{cos}^4x}$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

there's:

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{dx}{\mathrm{sin}^4x+
\mathrm{cos}^4x}$$

I was always confused if it is possible to solve this integral not using Tangent half-angle substitution? Because it takes much time for calculus only, is there another way?

Comment: use the weierstrass substution

Comment: Which one is ur question, the title or the content?

Comment: There was typo in the title, fixed now